# Internal Server Error - Updating records

Tags: apex, trigger, error

I'm getting this error: FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error. Based on the flags that I put on the code, the error happens when I'm trying to update a (large) list of records that I previously query. I think it's a time of process/memory issue because I get the error always after 10 minutes and when I run the code a second time, it works fine (I guess the data is cached).
(All this is happening in a before insert trigger of a different object)
What do you guys think? Maybe creating a batch class will solve this problem?

Thank you!! (and sorry for my english)

Comment: What kind of Internal error is there? Please put more details regarding error.

Comment: Hi! All I get is "An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 1489928313-54769 (-1775489667)", that's it =(

Comment: Check this https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019fygQAA if it works

Comment: Can you please check debug log for this operation.
Also you say error comes after 10 minutes which means you are doing some asynchronous operation. Can you please check the governor limits against your code https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Comment: Welcome to SFSE; to get the most from the Community, please see [ask]. Most likely, you will need to contact SFDC Support as you have encountered a gack

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update them one by one you will run into the Salesforce governor limit for DML operations which is limited to 150.

If you use collections you can update them more efficiently and the limits might be sufficient.

It's always helpful to include an example in your post if you need more detailed advice.